# Transforming data using Python Pandas (or M) in Power Query for PowerBi

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi, powerquery

I have some data about projects I would like to transform in a way that makes it easier to analyse with PowerBi.

The data looks like this:

| Project Number | Project Name | Planned Start Date | SM1 | SM2 | SM3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | A | Apr-21 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 10001 | B | Jun-21 | 40 | 50 | 60 |
| 10002 | C | Sep-22 | 70 | 80 | 90 |

[image]

The so called 'SavingMonths' are values that correspond to the Project's performance and each sequential column represents the next month based on the project's start date.

For example, Project A starts in April 2021, therefore SavingsMonth1=April-21, SavingsMonth2=May-21... and so on.

I would like to get it in this format:

[image]

In this way, I can now filter/sum 'Savings' column by date.

I'm not a programmer, but I do know *some* Python and thought the Pandas library may help, however I've only just started learning it. I don't know M at all, however I realised I can conduct transformations with Python in Power Query, which is nice.

Comment: It's a fair question, but could you please copy/paste your data as text, not as an image.

Comment: I've edited it, hope that's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people responding to this question are mostly correct, it's almost an unpivot, with the exception of the incrementing months.  We can use `melt` to unpivot, but then we have to add some date offsets to get the months right and then convert them back to the original format.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Project Number':[10000,10001,10002],
                   'Project Name':['A','B','C'],
                  'Planned Start Date':['Apr-21','Jun-21','Sep-22'],
                  'SavingsMonth1':[10,40,70],
                  'SavingsMonth2':[20,50,80],
                  'SavingsMonth3':[30,60,90]})


df['Planned Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime('01-'+df['Planned Start Date'])

df.sort_values(by='Planned Start Date', inplace=True)

df = df.melt(id_vars=['Project Number','Project Name', 'Planned Start Date'], value_name='Savings')
df['offset'] = df['variable'].str.extract('(\d)').astype(int).sub(1)
df['Planned Start Date'] = (df['Planned Start Date'].dt.to_period('M') + df['offset']).dt.strftime('%b-%y')
df = df.sort_values(by='Project Number').drop(columns=['variable','offset'])


print(df)
```

Output

```
  Project Number Project Name Planned Start Date  Savings
0           10000            A             Apr-21       10
3           10000            A             May-21       20
6           10000            A             Jun-21       30
1           10001            B             Jun-21       40
4           10001            B             Jul-21       50
7           10001            B             Aug-21       60
2           10002            C             Sep-22       70
5           10002            C             Oct-22       80
8           10002            C             Nov-22       90
```

Comment: I think this solution will work for me with a bit of tweaking, thank you so much Chris!

How would you handle NaN in the Planned Start Date?

Comment: Maybe fill it with a date from 1970, then after the calculations replace the 1970 dates with NaN again?  Hard to say for sure, sort of depends on your goals

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery (M) assuming the date starts off as a text column this (a) unpivots (b) converts the text to a date (c) adds X months to that based off the number of original columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Project Number", "Project Name", "Planned Start Date"}, "Ignore", "Savings"),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Mod Index" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", each Number.Mod(_,List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(Source))-3), Int64.Type}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Mod Index", "Planned Start Date", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Planned Start Date.1", "Planned Start Date.2"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Custom", each Date.FromText("01 "& [Planned Start Date.1] & "20"&[Planned Start Date.2])),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Date2", each  Date.AddMonths([Custom],[Index])),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Date", each Date.ToText([Date2],"MMM-yy")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Project Number", "Project Name", "Savings", "Date"})
 in  #"Removed Other Columns"
```

[image]

You need to replace Excel.CurrentWorkbook with Excel.WorkBook in Power BI

Answer (score 0):

This with Power Query but with little shorter code and independent on the number of columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Project Number", "Project Name", "Planned Start Date"}, "Ignore", "Savings"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Planned Start Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date", each Date.AddMonths([Planned Start Date] ,  Number.FromText(Text.End([Ignore],1))-1),  type date),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Ignore"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).